# Empty dialog in MahApps ShowMessageAsync

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mahapps.metro

I'm having a problem with ShowMessageAsync. It is giving me an empty dialog, for example I'm typing something like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.ShowMessageAsync("lala", "something else");
}
```

And my result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing a `ResourceDictionary`.  What do you have in your application.xaml?

[MahApps.Metro issue for reference](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/1563)